# Does data table guarantee the same order after group by calculation?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table).

```r
# Load package
library(data.table)

# Set RNG seed
set.seed(42)

# Create dummy data
dt <- data.table(alpha = sample(letters[1:3], 27, replace = TRUE), beta = 1:27)

# Peek
dt
#>     alpha beta
#>  1:     a    1
#>  2:     a    2
#>  3:     a    3
#>  4:     a    4
#>  5:     b    5
#>  6:     b    6
#>  7:     b    7
#>  8:     a    8
#>  9:     c    9
#> 10:     c   10
#> 11:     a   11
#> 12:     a   12
#> 13:     b   13
#> 14:     b   14
#> 15:     b   15
#> 16:     c   16
#> 17:     c   17
#> 18:     a   18
#> 19:     a   19
#> 20:     c   20
#> 21:     a   21
#> 22:     c   22
#> 23:     a   23
#> 24:     a   24
#> 25:     b   25
#> 26:     c   26
#> 27:     b   27
#>     alpha beta
```

Now, I want to perform a group by calculation.

```r
# Perform calculation by group
dt[, gamma := beta * .N, by = "alpha"]

# Peek
dt
#>     alpha beta gamma
#>  1:     a    1    12
#>  2:     a    2    24
#>  3:     a    3    36
#>  4:     a    4    48
#>  5:     b    5    40
#>  6:     b    6    48
#>  7:     b    7    56
#>  8:     a    8    96
#>  9:     c    9    63
#> 10:     c   10    70
#> 11:     a   11   132
#> 12:     a   12   144
#> 13:     b   13   104
#> 14:     b   14   112
#> 15:     b   15   120
#> 16:     c   16   112
#> 17:     c   17   119
#> 18:     a   18   216
#> 19:     a   19   228
#> 20:     c   20   140
#> 21:     a   21   252
#> 22:     c   22   154
#> 23:     a   23   276
#> 24:     a   24   288
#> 25:     b   25   200
#> 26:     c   26   182
#> 27:     b   27   216
#>     alpha beta gamma
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The resulting data table is in the same order as the original data table.

My question: is this behaviour **guaranteed** or should I always reorder after a group by calculation to ensure the same order as before the calculation?

Comment: see the `by` argument in `?data.table`

Comment: I think the answer is yes but (@chinsoon12) I didn't find the documentation terribly clear *"[...] order of the rows within each group is preserved, as is the order of the groups."*

Comment: @sindri_baldur :) you can do a PR in github.com/rdatatable

Comment: @chinsoon12 done: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4281

Comment: please provide an answer to the question, you can always self answer it.